# My VSCode open git merge diff file no highlighting and tool bar. How do I reopen it?

Tags: visual-studio-code

this VSCode for Web, it's normal

[image]

this VSCode for Local, its not normal

[image]

Comment: It is a bug in vscode: Some files just do this.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same. It happened after one of the updates for VS Code recently. But to ensure that it is not caused by any extension, please try to disable them all and see if issue has gone.